# Finding out npm version from package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, ts-node

I have a node app built with an unknown node and npm version. Is there any way to guess the version, or at least a version range, from `package-lock.json`?

I do have `"lockfileVersion": 1,`, which means npm v5 or v6. Any way I can get more granularity?

The reason I need it is, I am getting a bunch of errors like these when running `ts-node`, unless I delete and rebuild `package-lock.json`. Which I'd rather not do, for various reasons.

```
      ts.Debug.assert(typeof typeReferenceDirectiveName === "string", "Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.");
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. If I really wanted to go overboard with this, I'd write a script with different nvm versions in a loop.

Answer (score 11):

Simply search for "@types/node" inside package.json. It will give you node version used. Now search the relative npm version installed for the node version.

```
"@types/node": {
      "version": "16.9.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/node/-/node-16.9.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KDazLNYAGIuJugdbULwFZULF9qQ13yNWEBFnfVpql......",
      "dev": true
    },
```

Comment: How to find the npm version for this node version?

Comment: Never seen "@types/node" in any package.json in countless projects. I suppose you'll only find it if you intentionally add it beforehand.

Comment: @IceFire you will find the repected npm version for that node version https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: Thanks for the note!
They would have made it really easier by just specifying both the npm + node version at the top of the package.json file...

Comment: Yeah that would be nice. Doesn't requires much efforts even. @IceFire